# Syncing Photo Library on iPhone, laptop, and Google Photos

Tags: icloud, photos, data-synchronization, google-photos

I've looked all around, and I am aware that this is simple, but I have had immense trouble finding a straight answer.

I simply want the actions made on one device to affect the photo on all libraries as it is supposed to.

If I delete or edit a photo on my Photos app on my laptop, how long does it take for that effect to occur on the iPhone? Because, as of now, it is not quick.

Also, is there no way to have a delete affect photos that have already auto-synced with Google Photos? Why can it work one way (Google deletes affecting iCloud photos) but not the other way around??

This integration that is meant to make things easier is not always the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to iPhone iCloud Photos and Photos App on Mac with iCloud Photos enabled. When you delete photos on either of the devices, the update will reflect as soon as you see "Synced with iCloud Just Now".

[image]

I usually force-close the app and reopen it to trigger the sync. This works seamlessly on my devices.

I also use Google Photos as an alternative photo backup solution. There are two ways to delete Photos from Google Photos.

1. Google Photos app on iPhone

If you open the Google Photos app on iPhone and delete any picture on the iPhone. It will delete the photo from the Photos app as well. As it's showing the same library that is common with the Apple Photos app.

[image]

2. Google Photos on Web (photos.google.com)

If you delete a photo from Google Photos on the web, there is no way for the iPhone Google Photos app to delete it from the iCloud Library that is shown on the iPhone Photos app or Photos app on Mac.

Once you delete it on Google Photos Web, it won't show up in the Google Photos iPhone app but that deleted picture will still be available on the Photos app.

My suggestion is if you want to delete pictures and have them reflect everywhere, delete the pictures using Google Photos app on iPhone.